# Illustrator ScriptUI nested dialog box buttons not running propertly

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe-illustrator

Hi I'm not a programmer and have little knowledge in javascript and I want to create a script UI for adobe illustrator with nested dialog box. can somebody tell me what wrong with this code that I do. This code do is make a popup diaglog box or window and when you press a button will close the previous dialog box and will popup another dialog box and can close at any point. Looking forward to guiding me to make it run and I appreciate your help

```
var ph = createLayer();

alert( test);

function createLayer() 
   {
    var tier = new Window ('dialog', "Select Layer"); 
    tier.alignChildren = "left";
    var c1 = tier.add ("checkbox", undefined, "W1");
    var c2 = tier.add ("checkbox", undefined, "V1");
    var c3 = tier.add ("checkbox", undefined, "S1");
    var c4 = tier.add ("checkbox", undefined, "S2");
    c1.value = false;
    var tierButtonGroup = tier.add ("group");
    tierButtonGroup.orientation = "row";
    tierBtnOK = tierButtonGroup.add('button', undefined, 'OK');
    tierBtnCancel = tierButtonGroup.add('button', undefined, 'Cancel'),

    tierBtnOK.onClick = function()
    {
        tier.close(1)
    };
var Scope = tier.show();

        if (Scope == 1)
        {
            var jobTier = new Window ('dialog', "Select Project Scope"); 
            jobTier.orientation = "row";
            var t1 = jobTier.add ("button", undefined, "TIER 1");
            var t2 = jobTier.add ("button", undefined, "TIER 2");
            t1.onClick = function()
            {
                jobTier.close(1)

            };
        
            var type = jobTier.show();
        
            if (type == 1)
            {
                //Dialog Box city
                alert("Layers has been Created");
                var typeGauge = new Window ('dialog', "Type Gauge"); 
                typeGauge.orientation = "row";
                var tg1 = typeGauge.add ("button", undefined, "quiapo");
                var tg2 = typeGauge.add ("button", undefined, "manila");
               tg1.onClick= function()
                    {   
                         typeGauge.close(1);
                    };

                var gauge = typeGauge.show();
                if (gauge == 1) {
                    alert ("quiapo TypeGauge has been added")
                }
                else
                {
                    alert ("manila TypeGauge has been added")
                }
                typeGauge.close();
            }
        
            else
            {
                alert ("Revised Layers has been Created");
                      
            }
            jobTier.close();
            
        }
        else
        {
            return ("Create Layer has been Canceled");
                   
        }
tier.close();
```

};